# How to parse json to a database?

Tags: java, sql, database, json

I have a complex json written in a string. I know java and a little of mysql. I need to make a database out of the json.

I'm using some twitter data so the tweets contain the description of the user who tweeted it and in case it's been retweeted, it contains the description of the user who tweeted it before this user.

My objective is to create a user table ( or array or any other data structure ) which contains all the tweets this user tweeted, and all his tweets which have been retweeted.

The tweet object contains around 50-80 objects so giving an example here will make this post really long.

Example

```
StatusJSONImpl{createdAt=Wed Sep 28 12:04:55 IST 2011, id=118936707830775808, text='RT @nytimesbits: Google's Biggest Threat Is Google http://t.co/kTNqJFJC', source='web', isTruncated=false, inReplyToStatusId=-1, inReplyToUserId=-1, isFavorited=false, inReplyToScreenName='null', geoLocation=null, place=null, retweetCount=6, wasRetweetedByMe=false, contributors=null, annotations=null, retweetedStatus=StatusJSONImpl{createdAt=Wed Sep 28 05:35:26 IST 2011, id=118838689248985088, text='Google's Biggest Threat Is Google http://t.co/kTNqJFJC', source='<a href="http://www.nytimes.com/twitter" rel="nofollow">The New York Times</a>', isTruncated=false, inReplyToStatusId=-1, inReplyToUserId=-1, isFavorited=false, inReplyToScreenName='null', geoLocation=null, place=null, retweetCount=6, wasRetweetedByMe=false, contributors=null, annotations=null, retweetedStatus=null, userMentionEntities=[], urlEntities=[URLEntityJSONImpl{start=34, end=54, url=http://t.co/kTNqJFJC, expandedURL=http://nyti.ms/pR9DfX, displayURL=nyti.ms/pR9DfX}], hashtagEntities=[], user=UserJSONImpl{id=14434070, name='NYTimes Bits Blog', screenName='nytimesbits', location='The Cloud', description='News and analysis on tech and business. Also here: select retweets from NYT tech writers and friends. Account maintained by David F. Gallagher (@davidfg).', isContributorsEnabled=true, profileImageUrl='http://a1.twimg.com/profile_images/108833947/bits75_normal.jpg', profileImageUrlHttps='https://si0.twimg.com/profile_images/108833947/bits75_normal.jpg', url='http://nytimes.com/bits', isProtected=false, followersCount=53180, status=null, profileBackgroundColor='9ae4e8', profileTextColor='000000', profileLinkColor='0000ff', profileSidebarFillColor='e0ff92', profileSidebarBorderColor='87bc44', profileUseBackgroundImage=true, showAllInlineMedia=false, friendsCount=139, createdAt=Fri Apr 18 20:49:26 IST 2008, favouritesCount=5, utcOffset=-18000, timeZone='Eastern Time (US & Canada)', profileBackgroundImageUrl='http://a3.twimg.com/profile_background_images/4780380/twitter_post.png', profileBackgroundImageUrlHttps='https://si0.twimg.com/profile_background_images/4780380/twitter_post.png', profileBackgroundTiled=true, lang='en', statusesCount=6360, isGeoEnabled=false, isVerified=true, translator=false, listedCount=4671, isFollowRequestSent=false}}, userMentionEntities=[UserMentionEntityJSONImpl{start=3, end=15, name='NYTimes Bits Blog', screenName='nytimesbits', id=14434070}], urlEntities=[URLEntityJSONImpl{start=51, end=71, url=http://t.co/kTNqJFJC, expandedURL=http://nyti.ms/pR9DfX, displayURL=nyti.ms/pR9DfX}], hashtagEntities=[], user=UserJSONImpl{id=17989546, name='Wolfgang Fasching-K.', screenName='wwwof', location='Vienna', description='Digital ist besser. Fokus: IT & Internet, World News & US Politik, Medien & Pop/Kultur. http://www.riverone.at', isContributorsEnabled=false, profileImageUrl='http://a0.twimg.com/profile_images/67758989/SF050069-w_normal.JPG', profileImageUrlHttps='https://si0.twimg.com/profile_images/67758989/SF050069-w_normal.JPG', url='null', isProtected=false, followersCount=59, status=null, profileBackgroundColor='C0DEED', profileTextColor='333333', profileLinkColor='0084B4', profileSidebarFillColor='DDEEF6', profileSidebarBorderColor='C0DEED', profileUseBackgroundImage=true, showAllInlineMedia=false, friendsCount=64, createdAt=Tue Dec 09 17:09:35 IST 2008, favouritesCount=0, utcOffset=3600, timeZone='Vienna', profileBackgroundImageUrl='http://a3.twimg.com/profile_background_images/234523169/Naschmarkt-Wien-Juni10-2010-s.jpg', profileBackgroundImageUrlHttps='https://si0.twimg.com/profile_background_images/234523169/Naschmarkt-Wien-Juni10-2010-s.jpg', profileBackgroundTiled=true, lang='en', statusesCount=269, isGeoEnabled=false, isVerified=false, translator=false, listedCount=4, isFollowRequestSent=false}}
```

Comment: This is actually 2 questions in one - how to parse JSON and how to persist data in a database. Which part is difficult?

Comment: This is not valid JSON, are you sure?

Comment: This is the entity. even if it's not json :( . Any solutions?

Comment: @Rohan: The first thing to do is to find out what the format is meant to be so you can parse it correctly (or find a parser for it rather than writing one). That's step 1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For JSON parsing, I recommend [Jackson](http://jackson.codehaus.org). Also, in order to validate your input, you should have a look at JSON Schema (for which I have an implementation if you want).

Here is how to parse a JSON in a string using Jackson:

```
final ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();

final JsonNode node = mapper.readTree(yourInput);

// Access members:

node.get(0); // access node 0 of an array

for (final JsonNode entry: node) {
    ... // cycle through array nodes
}

node.get("foo"); // access property "foo" of an object

node.get("foo").getTextValue(); // access as a text

// etc etc
```

It also has a s*load of options to serialize to POJOs if that's what you want.

Answer (score 1):

Your first step will be to parse the JSON to get an object graph, using a library like [gson](http://code.google.com/p/google-gson/) or any of several others.

Then (and this seems really general, but it's a pretty open question) it's a matter of determining what the schema should be, creating the tables, and looping through the object graph populating them.

You might look at "document databases" (so-called [NoSQL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NoSQL)) rather than SQL ones if you're allowed to, as they usually allow the schema to be more fluid.

Comment: +1 for splitting the question into the 2 component parts (JSON parsing and persistence). I don't really agree yet with the NoSQL comment - it all depends on the usage of the data in the database.

Comment: @extraneon: Yes, it totally depends, OP should use an SQL RDBMS if that's a better fit for the problem. Always pick the right tool for the job. :-)

Answer (score 0):

If your problem is just with Twitter, you can look for dedicated APIs like Twiiter4J or Spring Social, that should provides ready java beans for tweets. 
If you're realizing a small project Gson is the best solution for parsing. But if your making something more sophisticated, I suggest you to use Jackson for parsing and Hibernate as a middleware between application and sql database.